# popup onClick without get

Tags: jquery, popup, href

I've a question about href optimization:

there's a menu:

```
<li class="leest-it">

<a href="**index.php/share-with-a-friendwidth520&shareitwithafriendurl=/index.php/foudler/foulder1/foulder2/banana/index.html**" class="link js-lightbox"><i class="ico iccc-kontkt"></i>Share with a friend</a>

</li>
```

how can I reduce it to just

> index.php/share-with-a-friend ?

with jquery plug-in having class sharewithafriendmodule?

Comment: Use `html5's data` attribute, i.e. `data-width='520' data-url='/index.php/foudler/foulder1/foulder2/banana/index.html'`, like this.

Comment: but it will be the same thing I've had. The goal is to haveindex.php/share-with-a-friend